# Problemas sql para consulta de reservas

Tags: php, sql

Estoy creando una pequeña aplicación web de reserva de barcos, donde el cliente puede consultar cuáles están disponibles y, en base a esta información, reservar uno de la lista.

Mi script PHP de consulta es este (también [aquí](http://textuploader.com/d5ocz)):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

include ("../base/conexion/conexion.php");


        $fecha_i = "2016-10-22";

        //$fecha_inicio = $_POST['fecha_inicio'];
        $fecha_inicio=   date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha_i) );
        //$inicio_f = str_replace('/', '-', $fecha_inicio);
        //$inicio = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($inicio_f));


        $fecha_f = "2016-10-22";

        //$fecha_fin      = $_POST['fecha_fin'];
        $fecha_fin  =   date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha_f ) );
        //$fin_f = str_replace('/', '-', $fecha_fin);
        //$fin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fin_f));




//-------------------------Rango de Fechas -------------------------
function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo = null)
{
    // takes two dates formatted as YYYY-MM-DD and creates an
    // inclusive array of the dates between the from and to dates.
    $aryRange=array();

    $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),     substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
    $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),     substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

    if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom)
    {
        array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom)); // first entry
        while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo)
        {
            $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
            array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
        }
    }
    return $aryRange;
}


    //Array de fechas presentes entre los rangos
    $array_rango_fechas = createDateRangeArray($fecha_inicio,$fecha_fin);
        //print_r($array_rango_fechas);

    //guardamos en una cadena de strings las fechas de dias reservados
    $fechas_a_reservar = implode(',' ,$array_rango_fechas );

    //print "Dias a reservar : ".$fechas_a_reservar."\n";


//------------------------------------------------


        //--Comprobar reservas--
        //reservas hechas entre los días elegidos - descartar de lista de barcos a mostrar


        $comprobar_reservas = mysqli_query($con," SELECT flotaid FROM disponibilidad WHERE DESDE >  $fecha_inicio 
            AND HASTA >  $fecha_fin" );
            //$comprobar_reservas_fin = mysql_query(" SELECT RESERVA FROM disponibilidad 
                //WHERE HASTA <= '2016-11-11'" );


            /*$comprobar_reservas = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT flotaid FROM reservas_prueba
                WHERE DESDE NOT IN ($fechas_a_reservar)

                union 

                SELECT flotaid FROM disponibilidad 
                WHERE HASTA IN ($fechas_a_reservar) ");*/

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($comprobar_reservas );

            print_r($row);

            /*$comprobar_reservas = mysql_query("SELECT flotaid  FROM disponibilidad 
                WHERE DESDE IN  ('$fechas_a_reservar') AND HASTA IN ('$fechas_a_reservar')" );*/

        //print_r($comprobar_reservas);
        //-->las querys devuelven la reserva del barco de ID = 4,
        //asi que se listan los barcos que no tengan esa ID

        //$row = mysql_fetch_array($comprobar_reservas);


        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($comprobar_reservas);

    if($num_rows > 0){
        //ARRAY que guardará los IDs/Nombres de barcos ya reservados,
        //y de esta forma sabremos cuáles estan disponibles descartando
        $barcos_no_disponibles = array();




        $i = 0;

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comprobar_reservas))
            {
               $lista_barcos_no_disponibles = $row;

            }


            $barcos_no_disponibles = implode(',' , $lista_barcos_no_disponibles );
            /*
            $barcos_no_disponibles_b = implode(',' ,$barcos_no_disponibles_b );
            $barcos_no_disponibles = $barcos_no_disponibles_a.$barcos_no_disponibles_b;*/

            //array_push();





        //print_r("Ids Barcos no disponibles : ".$barcos_no_disponibles."\n");


        //---COMPROBAR flota con ID (?)
            $comprobar_flota = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM flota WHERE FLOTAID NOT 
                IN ('$barcos_no_disponibles') ");

            $array_flota = array();
            $i = 0;


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($comprobar_flota)) {

                $array_flota[$i]['FLOTAID']         = $row['FLOTAID'];
                $array_flota[$i]['NOMBRE']          = utf8_encode($row['NOMBRE']);
                $array_flota[$i]['CARACTERISTICAS'] = utf8_encode($row['CARACTERISTICAS']);
                $array_flota[$i]['EQUIPAMIENTO']    = utf8_encode($row['EQUIPAMIENTO']);

                $i++;
            }

            //print_r($array_flota);


            header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8;");
            $json =  json_encode($array_flota,JSON_HEX_QUOT);
            if(empty($json)){
                die("no funciona");
            }else{
                echo json_encode($array_flota);
            }
            exit;

    }else{
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        echo json_encode(array());
        exit;
    }   

?>
```

Pasos para reservar:

1. El cliente especifica las fechas en las que quiere tener reservado el barco, utilizando unos campos `input` de los que se muestra un calendario.
2. La información se manda mediante AJAX a un script que hace la consulta.
   Se crea una cadena con las fechas presentes dentro del rango entre **Fecha de inicio** y **Fecha de fin** de reserva.
   Los reservas existentes que posean fechas dentro de ese rango no se mostrarán, las otras sí.
3. El usuario obtiene una lista de barcos disponibles. Especifica sus datos y manda la reserva a la web.

Estoy seguro que mi query de comprobación de reservas no está todo lo correcto que debería, ya que **no me devuelve las fechas que quiero**. A veces va mal,a veces sólo la última.

Comment: Bien pues,ahora que utilizo la query que elegí en este tema,        $comprobar_reservas_disponibilidad = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT flotaid 
   FROM disponibilidad 
   WHERE ('$fecha_inicio' BETWEEN DESDE AND HASTA) AND ('$fecha_fin' BETWEEN DESDE AND HASTA) ORDER BY flotaid");    Esta devuelve las fechas correctas la mayor parte de las veces,pero,si especifico un rango de dias muy alto,aparecen cada vez menos..No deberían de listarse cada vez menos(filtrarse más dias) cuanto mayor sea el filtro?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT flotaid 
FROM disponibilidad 
WHERE ($fecha_inicio BETWEEN DESDE AND HASTA) AND ($fecha_fin BETWEEN DESDE AND HASTA)
```

En el query valido ambas fechas: la de inicio y fin, ya que lo que se debe validar el intervalo de fecha dado y no una sola fecha.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Como habitualmente no utilizo between y sí he podido probar queries similares a "WHERE X = Y AND WHERE A = B",no imaginaba que diera tan buen resultado :D me lo apunto!

Answer (score 0):

si lo que buscas es saber la disponibilidad entre un rango de fechas lo que puedes probar es de esta manera:

`SELECT flotaid FROM disponibilidad WHERE DESDE >  $fecha_inicio AND HASTA < $fecha_fin"`

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que los campos `DESDE` y `HASTA` tengan tipo de datos "date", para que la comparación se haga correctamente, la forma más sencilla sería:

```
SELECT flotaid FROM disponibilidad WHERE DESDE >= '$fecha_inicio' AND HASTA <= '$fecha_fin'
```

- `$fecha_inicio` y `$fecha_fin` con formato `"aaaa-mm-dd"`;

Answer (score 0):

solo como comentario adicional

las variables de fecha en la cadena del query debería estar entre comillas

```
"SELECT flotaid FROM disponibilidad WHERE DESDE >  '$fecha_inicio' AND HASTA < '$fecha_fin'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos por vuestras respuestas,pero solamente consigo listar el último barco de los resultados,es decir,si me devuelve los IDs 1,2 y 3,únicamente devuelve el num 3.
A ver qué está mal.