# Consulta sobre fechas PHP y Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

tengo dos tablas ,una con alojamientos: (idalojamiento,tipo,numeroalojamiento) y otra con reservas donde guardo los datos del huesped con la fecha de inicio y la fecha de fin de la reserva.

Mi consulta es como como puedo traer las habitaciones disponibles en futuras reservas mandando solo las fecha de inicio y fechas de fin de reserva . Tengo esta consulta en Mysql que si funciona pero si selecciono un dia anterior a esa fechafin  me devuelve todas las habitaciones disponibles y estaria mal.

Consulta Mysql:

```
SELECT idalojamiento,alojamiento,numero FROM alojamientos WHERE idalojamiento NOT IN
(SELECT alojamiento FROM reservas WHERE estado = 0 AND ( (fechareserva BETWEEN :fechaconsulta AND :fechacheckout) AND ( fechafin BETWEEN :fechaconsulta AND :fechacheckout) ) )
```

si ingreso las fechas de inicio y fin y existen reservas en esa fechas funciona pero si ingreso un dia antes de la fecha fin me devuelve todos los alojamientos disponibles. Como podria consultar tambien las fechas intermedias ? . Gracias.

Comment: Pon un dbfiddle o algo con ejemplos de los datos que tienes y el resultado esperado.

Comment: ¿Te sirve esta pregunta y sus respuestas? [Consulta de Reservas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/27543/80870)

Comment: aparentemente voy bien encaminado , lo que sucede es que al utilizar BETWEEN para consultar las fechas de fin y de inicio de reserva solo me compara en esas fechas en especifico . no las intermedias , es decir yo consulto por decir un dia antes de la fecha de fin y me devuelve todos los alojamientos disponibles. Es raro.